# PyUnit tearDown and setUp vs __init__ and __del__

Tags: python, unit-testing

Is there a difference between using tearDown and setUp versus `__init__` and `__del__` when using the pyUnit testing framework?  If so, what is it exactly and what is the preferred method of use?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`setUp` is called before every test, and `tearDown` is called after every test.
`__init__` is called once when the class is instantiated -- but since [a new
`TestCase` instance is created *for each individual test method*](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/unittest.html#organizing-test-code), `__init__` is
also called once per test.

You generally do not need to define `__init__` or `__del__` when writing unit
tests, though you could use `__init__` to define a constant used by many tests.

---

This code shows the order in which the methods are called:

```
import unittest
import sys

class TestTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def __init__(self, methodName='runTest'):
        # A new TestTest instance is created for each test method
        # Thus, __init__ is called once for each test method
        super(TestTest, self).__init__(methodName)
        print('__init__')

    def setUp(self):
        #
        # setUp is called once before each test
        #
        print('setUp')

    def tearDown(self):
        #
        # tearDown is called once after each test
        #
        print('tearDown')

    def test_A(self):
        print('test_A')

    def test_B(self):
        print('test_B')

    def test_C(self):
        print('test_C')



if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv.insert(1, '--verbose')
    unittest.main(argv=sys.argv)
```

prints

```
__init__
__init__
__init__
test_A (__main__.TestTest) ... setUp
test_A
tearDown
ok
test_B (__main__.TestTest) ... setUp
test_B
tearDown
ok
test_C (__main__.TestTest) ... setUp
test_C
tearDown
ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it helped me (a Python newbie). I also found that there's an alternative to `__init__` and `__del__`: Using the `setUpClass` and `tearDownClass` functions. These have to be class methods, in other words you have to add `@classmethod` above them.  [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/unittest.html#class-and-module-fixtures)

Comment: According to here (https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/unittest.html#organizing-test-code), "~TestCase.setUp, ~TestCase.tearDown, and ~TestCase.__init__ will be called once per test.".

Comment: @ismailarilik: Thanks very much for the correction!